# All possible combinations from 3 columns of a table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am looking for some sort of example or idea how I can create all possible combinations from 3 columns of a database table in oracle.

I have data like below table-

```
Name ID CODE POS_4 POS_5 POS_6
XJ   21 SAJ     A   
XJ   21 SAJ         A   
XJ   21 SAJ         C   
XJ   21 SAJ         J   
XJ   21 SAJ         L   
XJ   21 SAJ               10
XJ   21 SAJ               12
XJ   21 SAJ               14
```

And result I am expecting like below-

```
A_A_10
A_A_12
A_A_14
A_C_10
A_C_12
A_C_14
and so on...
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: All combinations, regardless of `Name`, `ID` or `CODE`?  Or only combinations in the ***same*** `Name`, `ID` and `CODE`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cross join`:

```
select p4.pos_4 || '_' || p5.pos_5 || '_' || p6.pos_6
from (select distinct pos_4 from t) p4 cross join
     (select distinct pos_5 from t) p5 cross join
     (select distinct pos_6 from t) p6;
```

If you want to eliminate `NULL` values, then include:

```
where p4.pos_4 is not null and p5.pos_5 is not null and p6.pos_6 is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join. ie:

```
select Pos_4, Pos_5, Pos_6
from 
(select Pos_4 from myTable where Pos_4 is not null) T1
cross join (select Pos_5 from myTable where Pos_5 is not null) T2
cross join (select Pos_6 from myTable where Pos_6 is not null) T3;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the solution, it worked.
However sometimes I have some null rows against any of the columns (POS_4/POS_5/POS_6)
 and using 

Pos_4 is not null/Pos_5 is not null/Pos_6 is not null
Will not give any result if any of them will be completely null.

Example-
`Name ID CODE POS_4 POS_5 POS_6`
`XJ   21 SAJ         J `
`XJ   21 SAJ         L `
`XJ   21 SAJ                   10`
`XJ   21 SAJ                   12`
`XJ   21 SAJ                   14`

In above table assume POS_6 is completely null. It could be POS_4/POS_5 for any other ID.
Any suggestion to avoid this.

Comment: @Jai, I am sorry I couldn't understand the problem and the output you need. Would you edit your question to show it?